# Запятая перед КАК не ставится?

Tags: пунктуация

Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав фразеологизма, запятая не ставится. Кто решает: фразеологизм это или нет ? Сейчас нашел у Гоголя пример:

18. Ноздрев был среднего роста, очень недурно сложенный молодец с полными, румяными щеками, с белыми, как снег, зубами и черными, как смоль, бакенбардами.

Как тут быть, если в тесте или диктанте попадется подобное предложение с примером,похожим на фразеологизм, и я выделю его запятыми, это будет считаться  как ошибка?

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200801002

Comment: "А если б он вез патроны?"

Answer (score 3):

Здесь важно учитывать порядок слов, смотреть, есть ли подмена слов в устойчивым словосочетании, выступает ли фразеологизм в роли сказуемого и т.п.

Ср.: Сальные свечи берегли как зеницу ока( С.-Щ). Но: Надо, как зеницу ока, хранить память о лучших людях своей стороны.

В первом предложении оборот тесно связан со сказуемом, запятой нет. Во втором примере на первый план выступает сравнение, оборот не связан со сказуемым, запятая нужна. 
Еще: черный как черт. А намосту, как черт, черный взметнулся плащ (Цвет.).

Answer (score 2):

1) "Ноздрев был среднего роста, очень недурно сложенный молодец с полными, румяными щеками, с белыми, как снег, зубами и черными, как смоль, бакенбардами".

Так напечатано в издании 1842 года, это авторская пунктуация при отсутствии четких правил, существующих в настоящее время. В текстах того времени можно встретить оба варианта.

2) Фразеологические обороты с союзом КАК обычно обозначают ВЫСОКУЮ СТЕПЕНЬ ПРОЯВЛЕНИЯ признака или действия: белый как снег = очень белый. Такие обороты выступают в роли наречия, а одиночные наречия **обычно никто не обособляет, не спрашивая у них на то разрешения.**

3) Но не стоит считать, что фразеологический оборот не должен обособляться в обязательном порядке, и это  его неотъемлемое свойство.  Фразеологизмы с союзом КАК  НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЮТСЯ, являясь обстоятельствами образа действия или степени и занимая в предложении соответствующую позицию. Однако любые отклонения от этого стандарта  (распространенность, измененная позиция) приводят к ОБОСОБЛЕНИЮ оборота на письме и выделению его паузами в устной речи.

Сравним: Удивительный туман! Белый как снег, он лениво клубится над лугом. Белая, как первый снег, чайка летает над морем.

Answer (score 0):

> ...молодец с полными, румяными щеками, с белыми, как снег, зубами и черными, как смоль, бакенбардами"

Без запятой: молодец с полными, румяными щеками, с зубами белыми как снег,  и бакенбардами черными как смоль

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как надо, а в том, что будет. другое дело, что на подобные воаросы лучше вообще не отвечать.. Умозрительно.

Comment: Как скажете. Больше не буду)

Comment: Ну я запретить не могу. Это мое мнение, сложившееся на основании опыта. Я не против казуистики вообще, но тут, на ресурсе, посвященном русскому языку, подобное хитромудрие вызывает некоторые сомнения в благих намерениях автора. ОГсобенно, когда оное хитромудрие повторяется из раза в раз...  Ну согласитесь, человек не интересуется "как надо", а только "что будет", если он сделает по-своему. "А если я в колодей плюну, что будет?" "А если я сук обрублю, на котором сижу?" и проч.